# Why does returning a C-string from a function result in random characters?

Tags: c++, string, scope

I've had to stop coding so many projects because of this weird quirk that I'm fed up enough to ask and risk looking like an idiot, so here goes...

I wrote a function like this:

```
const char* readFileToString(const char* filename) {
    const char* result;
    std::ifstream t(filename);
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << t.rdbuf();
    result = buffer.str().c_str();
    return result;
}
```

I would expect that, if `file.txt` contains `hello`, that `readFileToString("file.txt")` should return `hello`. Instead, it returns garbled text, something along the lines of `H�rv�0`. However, if I put a `std::cout << result;`  just before the return, it'll print `hello`.

Is this some weird, impossible quirk with C++? How do I fix it?

Comment: Returning pointers to local or temporary  variables is rarely a good idea. Just use std::string, returned by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's neither weird nor impossible; you returned a pointer to a buffer that went out of scope. The `const char*` doesn't "own" the string data, it only refers to it. Or, it used to! Once returned, that pointer is now invalid. You shall not dereference it.

I suggest you stick with `std::string` instead of venturing into advanced pointer techniques.

```
std::string readFileToString(const char* filename)
{
    std::ifstream t(filename);
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << t.rdbuf();
    return buffer.str();
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any way to avoid a copy here.

If you don't mind shuffling your design about a little, and if you have some way to avoid a stream-to-string copy down the line, you could do this instead:

```
void readFileToStream(const char* filename, std::ostream& os)
{
    std::ifstream t(filename);
    os << t.rdbuf();
}
```

You may wish to return `bool` signifying the stream's state, but again you can do that at the callsite anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the commentary below:

```
const char* readFileToString(const char* filename) {
    const char* result;
    std::ifstream t(filename);
    std::stringstream buffer; // Behind the scenes some memory will/is allocated
    buffer << t.rdbuf();      // Memory is getting filled 
    result = buffer.str().c_str(); // Getting the address of that memory
    return result;
    // Buffer getting destroyed along with the allocated memory (what result points to)
}
```

.. Here results points to an invalid memory location

So hence it being corrupted